# What is the meaning of the particle と in this sentence?

Tags: particle-と

> １浪でおよそ20％台の合格率で、2浪以上ではおおよそ2～3％台**と**かなり低迷しています。([source](https://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/67786/))

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56316/9831